# Hide coupon field for specific user role (wholesalers) in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am looking for a way to disable the coupon field for wholesalers in WooCommerce on the cart and checkout pages. I am using a custom theme and have the WooCommerce Role Based Methods plug-in in conjunction with WooCommerce Wholesale Pricing. I have tried the following in `functions.php`:

```
// hide coupon field on cart page for wholesale
function hide_coupon_field_on_cart( $enabled ) {

    if( ! current_user_can( 'wholesale_customer' ) && is_cart() ) {
        $enabled = false;
    }

    return $enabled;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupons_enabled', 'hide_coupon_field_on_cart' );

// hide coupon field on checkout page for wholesale
function hide_coupon_field_on_checkout( $enabled ) {

    if( ! current_user_can( 'wholesale_customer' ) && is_checkout() ) {
        $enabled = false;
    }

    return $enabled;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupons_enabled', 'hide_coupon_field_on_checkout' );
```

But that didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is it this plugin you are using? http://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-wholesale-prices/5325378

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
function woo_get_user_role() {
  global $current_user;
  $user_roles = $current_user->roles;
  $user_role = array_shift($user_roles);
  return $user_role;
}

// hide coupon field on cart page for wholesale
function hide_coupon_field_on_cart( $enabled ) {
  if(woo_get_user_role() =='wholesale_customer' && is_cart() || is_checkout() ) {
    $enabled = false;
  }
  return $enabled;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupons_enabled', 'hide_coupon_field_on_cart' );
```

You can also merge both functions into one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
                if ( !($current_user instanceof WP_User) )
                   return true;
                $roles = $current_user->roles;
                foreach($roles as $role){
                    // wholesaler is your role name, not display name
                    if( $role == "wholesaler" ){
                        $isWholesalers = 1;
                    }
                }
                if(!isset($isWholesalers)){
                    return true;
                }
                if(is_cart()/*is_checkout*/ )
                       return false;
```